# Incorrect syntax with OPENDATASOURCE in Sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am stuck at passing the parameter to OPENDATASOURCE and got an error message:

> Msg 102, Incorrect syntax near 'SQLNCLI'
>
> ----@ConnectionString passing From UI

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT CM.CustomerId AS [Customer ID] from CardMaster CM inner join CUSTOMERTAIL CT
            on CM.CustomerId = CT.CustomerId
            INNER JOIN OPENDATASOURCE(SQLNCLI, @ConnectionString).MercFuelProd.dbo.CUSTOMER CR 
            ON CM.CustomerId = CR.CUSTID WHERE CM.CardNumber = @CardNumber) -
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 'SUCCESS'
        END
    ELSE
```

Pleas anyone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass string:

```
OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI'...
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx

Also you have some dash before the `BEGIN` keyword...